# No ethernet connection in Ubuntu 19.04 after changing motherboard

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, ethernet

so I've recently built a new PC and kept my SSD/HDD, so everything except my disk drive which has ubuntu installed on it changed. The ethernet connection doesn't work (it used to work on old PC on same ubuntu install), Wi-Fi still works through an USB adapter. Ethernet Connection works on another drive with Windows install so I know the port is working fine, it's only on Ubuntu. I'm looking for a way to get ethernet working without reinstalling ubuntu

**my ifconfig:**

```
r0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::3c60:9eff:fe5b:8d94  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 3e:60:9e:5b:8d:94  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 40313  bytes 5565185 (5.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1515  bytes 472236 (472.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 78701  bytes 6556181 (6.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 78701  bytes 6556181 (6.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:71:a9:c1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx0024010c2ae6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.41  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::bf4c:1503:726:f000  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:24:01:0c:2a:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 73240  bytes 82584023 (82.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 51703  bytes 7315654 (7.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

as you can see there's no eth0 or eth1 in ifconfig, maybe that has something to do with the problem?

**my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:**

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

**"*sudo lshw -C network*" output**:

```
    *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: 04:d4:c4:47:ce:15
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:126 memory:a5200000-a521ffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: br0
       serial: 3e:60:9e:5b:8d:94
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:71:a9:c1
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:2
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@3:13.4
       logical name: wlx0024010c2ae6
       serial: c6:35:71:76:9b:db
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt73usb driverversion=5.0.0-25-generic firmware=1.7 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network:3 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:71:a9:c1
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

***"cat /etc/network/interfaces"* output:**

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

***"cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml" output**

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: yes
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp0s31f6
```

also, it says 'Ethernet Network device not managed' when I click on the network icon on top right

**SPECS:**

```
ASUS Maximus XI Hero (No Wi-Fi)
Intel Core i9 9900k @ 3.6Ghz
MSI GEFORCE RTX 2080 Ti
32GB DDR4 Ram @ 2666MHz
```

Comment: Also posted on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425158

Comment: Please try to load the kernel-module for your I219-V Lan-Chipset with "sudo modprobe e1000e".

Comment: @Qterra, Is that supposed to give me any output on terminal? I ran that code but I feel like it didn't do anything

Comment: Please update Your question with output of the `sudo lshw -C network` command.

Comment: @darky modprobe will only generate outputs on errors. If your ethernet still not working, please add the informations Michael requested.

Comment: I've added the output of 'sudo lshw -C network'

Comment: We wonder why it is disabled. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555, added the result of the commands and thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file, please change both instances of enp0s31f6 to read eno1, the new logical name of your ethernet. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Your ethernet should now be working correctly. If not, try a reboot.

Comment: thank you so much! it worked, I can connect through ethernet now. And by the way, when I click the 'network icon' on top right, it still says Ethernet Network device not managed. is this normal?

Comment: You can have it managed by Network Manager or netplan but not conveniently or easily by both. If you'd prefer Network Manager, please ask a new question and I'll advise. Bear in mind, however, that your virtual bridge is *NOT* easily managed by NM. If everything now works as expected, I wouldn't change a thing!

Comment: You sir have saved me a lot of time today, I figured there was a configuration mismatch with the adapter after I replaced the motherboard, but wasn't too sure where to look. For me on a headless Ubuntu server 20.04.4 install the file was called `50-cloud-init.yaml`